# What are the differences between "The computer went on/off" and "The computer came on/off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In the dictionaries,

> **[come on](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come-on_1?q=come%20on)**:*To begin to operate.*
> Examples:
>
> - "Set the oven to **come on** at six."
> - "When does the heating **come on**?"

> **[go on](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-on?q=go%20on)**:*When a light, the electricity, etc., goes on, it starts to work.*
> Examples:
>
> - "Suddenly all the lights **went on**."

> **[go off](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-off#go_sng_290)**:*If a light, the electricity, etc. goes off, it stops working.*
> Examples:
>
> - "Suddenly the lights **went off**."
> - "The heating **goes off** at night."

So, can we say:

> *"The computer **went on/off**."*

And:

> *"The computer **came on/off.**"*

If yes, **What are the differences between them?**

Comment: *turn on/off* could be another phrasal verb here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, no difference

Both "The computer went on/off" and "The computer came on/off" are valid and natural nonstarters, and there is no significant difference in meaning. They may be used interchangeably.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we wouldn't use **came off** in this context. It's usually **come on/go off**. **Go on** is possible, but **come off** sounds odd.

Comment: @KateBunting, I changed a channel on my TV but there was nothing on the screen, although other channels were ok. Can I say "**the channel didn't come on**"?

Comment: Yes, you could say that.

Answer (score 3):

Native Speakers probably would not phrase it that way.

We would more likely say:

> The computer turned on

> The computer started

and

> The computer turned off

> The computer shut down